# What to considering when replacing disc brake calipers?

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake

I currently have an endurance road bike equipped with [Shimano 105 hydraulic disc brake calipers](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/shimano105-r7000/BR-R7070-R.html). Since I am transforming it into a gravel bike, I would like to change the calipers to the [Shimano GRX 810](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/grx-11-speed/BR-RX810-F.html) ones. I don't want to change the brake levers nor hoses though. Would it work? What do I have to consider when doing it?

Comment: Why do you want change the calipers? Are you changing disc sizes?

Comment: @airace3 sounds stupid, but just to have all components from the same groupset :)

Comment: If you’re not changing your levers, the components won’t all be from same group set.

Comment: @Bob what's the point?

Comment: Now I understand it is pointless :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-737&acid=C-499 I found this chart:

[image]

Here you can spot a GRX caliper BR-RX810 on the right and a 105-brifter ST-R7020 (you didn't state which exact one you own) on the left. So if that is your preferred combination, you should be good to go. I don't know if it will be any better than your existing system of 105 brifter+caliper.

Comment: Probably not, but I wanted it all to be from the same group set

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to change calipers. All Shimano Road/Gravel Calipers, except Dura Ace, are basically identical:

[image: GRX 810]

[image: GRX 400]

[image: 105]

They may differ in design/color and the brakepads that come with them when new.

If you still want to replace them:

1. Get new olives and pins.
2. Remove the hose from old caliper, cut it just above the old olive to remove olive and the pin.
3. Put new olive and pin on the hose and mount it to the new caliper.
4. Bleed the brakes.

But there wont be any difference, except the different text and color on the calipers.

Comment: Great response. Thanks!